# Generic Handler with ValidateAntiForgeryToken Att on MVC 4 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I search and try, but couldnt success. Is it possible use `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` with `Generic Handler (.ashx)`?

I tried this code, but not working.

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      //Process
    }
```

Thanks.